# Postgresql- divide sum by total already in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

I have a table with several time intervals as rows with one "total" row. I have four columns; car, bus, truck, and total, that refer to the number of vehicles leaving a warehouse at each time interval by category and the total number of vehicles at each time interval. My table looks like this:

```
time      car      truck    bus     total

12-6am    10         15      10       35

7am-12pm  8          12      8        28

Total     18         27     18        63
```

I want to create a percent total row that takes the total value in each row (35 and 28) and divides it by the maximum value in the total row (63).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the schema of your table, it doesn't make sense to have an extra row in it, but only an extra column.

However, even that is a bad idea. A database is not a spreadsheet, where you have largely free-form data. It's a collection of tables. Total rows should be calculated with SELECT statements, not make some attempt to have them in the table. Unlike a spreadsheet, Postgres won't auto-update that as rows are added and deleted. (Note: Yes, sometimes you need to materialize this summary stuff for efficiency, but that's the advanced course.)

Comment: I should clarify- I created the "total" row based on a select statement and did a union with the table that had the time buckets in it. So I can redo the entire table as necessary; it came from a query of a much larger table.

Comment: Much better! But the column you are looking for needs a second pass, because the denominator isn't known as the DB scans the table. You can do this with a subselect, a CTE, and probably a few other ways.